# unable to fetch image from the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am trying to display images on my web page, the content is getting fetched from my database, but the issue I'm facing is in displaying the image. please, can anyone guide me how should I display the image?

I mean to say the path what I should give

here 'image' is my column name and this is my view

```
        <?php 
            if( !empty($results) ) {

                foreach($results as $row) {?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/');$image?>" alt="">
                  <h3><?php echo $row->title; ?></h3>
                  <p><?php echo $row->content; ?></p>
                </div> 
               <?php 

               } ?>

            <?php }
        ?>
```

Comment: what is name of column for the image in your table? i mean from where `$image`  is coming it is  from table or it is static

Comment: First, print the $row.    print_r($row);

Comment: it should be like this `<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$row->image);?>" alt="">`

Comment: from table im fetcing the image i mean to say the uploaded image is saved in the upload folder and the name is saved in database as 1.jpg,2.jpg like this

Comment: what is $image? is it a name of the image file on drive or encoded format like base64?

Comment: thanks pradeep for ur answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use this :  `<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$row->image);?>" alt="">`

*The whole code should be like this :*

```
<?php 
            if( !empty($results) ) {

                foreach($results as $row) {?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$row->image);?>" alt="">
                  <h3><?php echo $row->title; ?></h3>
                  <p><?php echo $row->content; ?></p>
                </div> 
               <?php 

               } ?>

            <?php }
        ?>
```

Comment: pleasure is mine happy coding , pls check it as green also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220674/unable-to-store-the-multiselect-data-to-database

Comment: can u check this question             @pradeep

Answer (score 1):

If $image is the column name(which contains image name) then Replace

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/');$image?>" alt="">
```

with

```
 <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $row->image;?>" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$image` has image path then remove ';' and add '.' on `echo base_url('uploads/');$image?>` line

Comment: Not the only issue and already has an answer to this affect, please see my answer

Answer (score -1):

You issue here is the following code;

```
<?php echo base_url('uploads/');$image?>
```

This is because you are not concatenating the string, rather, just saying it's variable name, so, use of the following will provide the output;

```
<?php echo base_url('uploads/') . $image' ?>
```

This replaces the semi-colon part way through for a period (`.`) which is the PHP concatenation operator

Obviously, there is the issue you are not setting `$image`, which would require (before usage) of;

```
$image = $row['image_column_name'];
// Or
$image = $row->img_column_name
```