# unable to store the multiselect data to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

im trying to store the values in database, all the values are getting dtored in the database but the issue is with dropdown. when i try to upload the multiselect dropdown only 
the last selected value is getting stored, where as i want to store all the selected values in the database, can some one guide me how can i do that

```
    //----controller-----
    public function portfolio1()
        {  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_content', 'First content', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_content', 'Second content', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
            {
                $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH.'uploads/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( $this->upload->do_upload('filename') )
                {
                    //print_r($this->upload->data());die; 
                    $data['first_content'] = $this->input->post('first_content');
                    $data['second_content'] = $this->input->post('second_content');
                    $data['type'] = $this->input->post('type');
                    $data['filename'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');  

                    //Transfering data to Model
                    $this->Contact_model->portfolio1($data);
                    //Redirecting to success page
                    redirect(site_url('Home/portfolio1'));     
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    print_r($error);die;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                  $this->load->view('portfolio1'); 

            }
        } 


        //----model----------
        function portfolio1($data)
        {
            //saving records
            $this->db->insert('portfolio1', $data); 
        }


     //------view page-----


   <?php echo form_open_multipart('Home/portfolio1'); ?>
    <div style="padding-top:10%; padding-left:30%">
        <div>
            <textarea name="first_content" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
            <span><?php echo form_error("first_content");?></span>
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <textarea name="second_content" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
            <span><?php echo form_error("second_content");?></span>
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <select name="type" multiple>
                <option value="*">All Works</option>
                <option value=".bootstrap">Creative</option>
                <option value=".html">Photography</option>
                <option value=".wordpress">Web Development</option>
            </select>
            <span><?php echo form_error("type");?></span>
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="filename">
            <span><?php echo form_error("filename");?></span>
        </div><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Upload your html code too.

Comment: just updated sir please go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your multiselect part like this.

```
<select name="type[]" multiple>
    <option value="*">All Works</option>
    <option value=".bootstrap">Creative</option>
    <option value=".html">Photography</option>
    <option value=".wordpress">Web Development</option>
</select>
```

I have change the name from `type` to `type[]` so you will get all selected option.

**UPDATE**

```
if ( $this->upload->do_upload('filename') )
            {
                //print_r($this->upload->data());die; 
                $data['first_content'] = $this->input->post('first_content');
                $data['second_content'] = $this->input->post('second_content');
                $data['type'] = implode(",",$this->input->post('type'));
                $data['filename'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');  

                //Transfering data to Model
                $this->Contact_model->portfolio1($data);
                //Redirecting to success page
                redirect(site_url('Home/portfolio1'));     
            }
```

Now it will save `type` as comma separated in your table.

Comment: its not working sir instead the values are only not getting stored in database

Comment: In post you will get array of selected values so you have to convert it into string or its depend on how you handle this in table.

Comment: sir im new to this codeigniter please can you be little bit bref

Comment: the values are not getting stored in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174546/discussion-between-rakesh-varma-and-keerthi-patil).

Comment: can u just check this link

Answer (score 1):

> **all the values are getting dtored in the database but the issue is with dropdown. when i try to upload the multiselect dropdown only the last selected value is getting stored**

Can you please mention in which name your multiselect is posted, and I can't find your view page to check how your attributes in mentioned in dropdown

Comment: When you print the posted values in controller like this **print_r($this->input->post("type"));** you will get the values in array format as you mentioned the dropdown name as type[]. Your output will be like this ** Array ( [0] => .bootstrap [1] => .html ) ** . I have a doubt about your database structure, whether you are using seperate table for storing this dropdown table or else you are storing in a single field seperated by comma ?

Comment: im storing in single field using comma

Comment: If you are storing in a seperate table , use foreach inside your model so that you can store all the selected values in seperate row

If you are storing in a same table , then use implode(",",$this->input->post("type")); function to convert array into string separated by comma and store it in same table. hope it helps you

Comment: implode(",",$this->input->post("type")); sir i tried this but its not working

Comment: replace this **$data['type'] = $this->input->post('type');** with **$data['type'] = implode(",",$this->input->post('type'));** . You don't want to change anything. It will work

Comment: Please let me know what Error you are getting while using implode() function

Comment: actually in validation i was not using this type[]

Comment: can u just check this link

Comment: yeah sure... I need to know what type of error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

If your dropdown box is multiselect then you have to use array in name of select attribute.

```
<select name="type[]" multiple>
```

You will get all selected value in post variable like

```
<?Php $_POST["type"]; ?>
```

Comment: can u just check this link

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this problem before but I had a work around on the server side.

Normally you get your array values, which in your case, in **$_POST['type']**, right?
So what you wanna do is do it like this...

```
$type = implode(',', $_POST['type']);
```

And save it to your database as a comma separated values.
And each time you display those fields in your form you will convert them back to an array form and loop through each one of them so that they become selected by default.

```
$type = explode(',', $_POST['type']);
```

I'll just use the $_POST variable for uniformity but I guess you already get the idea. Hope this helps!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223033/error-in-creating-gallery-using-codeigniter

Comment: can u just check this link